# Select Method of Class Range Failed error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Cheers, everyone! The code below is supposed to transfer data from one workbook to another. I set both paths and everything. The code does half of its job. However, it tells me that class range is not selected properly and I don't understand what is it wrong.

In the code, i left the comment on the line in which I get the error. Furthermore, how I can make sure that every time when I transfer the data from wb2 to wb1 it won't overwrite the data that is already stored in wb1?

Thanks in advance!

Note:

- wb1 is the workbook that has the button to transfer the data and needs to be paste.
- wb2: is the workbook that needs to be opened and copy the data from.

  ```
  Private Sub Transferdata_Click()


  Dim intChoice As Integer
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim filname As String

     Dim wb1            As Workbook ' the workbook where I paste the data
     Dim wb2              As Workbook 'the workbook I copy the data

       Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook


      MsgBox ("Please open the workbook you need to transfer the data from")


  Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear

  intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

  If intChoice <> 0 Then

  strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
  msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)


  filname = Split(strPath, "\")(UBound(Split(strPath, "\")))

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath


     Windows(filname).Activate
      Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

     wb2.Sheets("File").Range("A3").Select ' I get the error here. don't understand why
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
      Selection.Copy

  wb1.Activate

     wb1.Sheets("File2").Select
     Range("A4").Select
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False ' how can I make sure here that every time when I copy the data from wb2 to wb1 won't overwrite the data that is already in wb1? to paste the data starting from the row that is empty? 



  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End If
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: You can't select a range unless its sheet and workbook are active. (You should also avoid selecting as it's generally unnecessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. Have cut out all the selects and activates and assigned workbook variables to both.

```
Private Sub Transferdata_Click()

Dim intChoice As Long
Dim strPath As String
Dim filname As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook ' the workbook where I paste the data
Dim wb2 As Workbook 'the workbook I copy the data

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please open the workbook you need to transfer the data from")
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
    msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    filname = Split(strPath, "\")(UBound(Split(strPath, "\")))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath)
    With wb2.Sheets("File")
        .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With
    With wb1.Sheets("File2")
        .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get the following error message `Object Variable or With block variable not set` in line `With wb1.Sheets("File2")`

Comment: Is the workbook you are pasting into definitely active when you run the macro? Using `Activeworkbook` is a bit dicey. If the code is in that file you can use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Comment: It says that it is Active. I tried to change to ThisWorkbook. Same error..

Comment: Can you try the name of the file instead `Set wb1 = Workbooks("name")`.

Comment: @SRJ, sorry for the late replay. The code works now. It was my fault as I didn't paid attention on the name of the sheet. This works awesome. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Rory mentioned in the comments, it would be best to avoid using .Select in a situation like this. I think it would be easier to Dim a range variable and use that to copy/paste:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wb2.Sheets("File").Range("A3")
    wb2.Sheets("File").Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

You can do the same with the paste operation. To avoid overwriting data, first check if any exists in the A4 cell. If there is data there you can use xlDown to get the last row with data and then go one past that.

```
Dim rng2 As Range
If wb1.Sheets("File2").Range("A4") = "" Then
    Set rng2 = wb1.Sheets("File2").Range("A4")
Else
    Set rng2 = wb1.Sheets("File2").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0)
End If
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```